# Size and Header Position of Modal Dialog

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

thanks in advance. I have modal dialog and two problems. I am using bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js. I did not change anything in bootstrap.min.css file.

My problems:

**1.** I do not know why but header text is on right aligned and close button is on the left side of it. How to do left alignment of header text and right alignment of close button? Please see the image.

[Modal Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T7Ge.jpg)

I got the code from w3schools.com to work on it.

Here is the code:

```html
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testmodal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="testmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h1 class="modal-title">Test</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I use bootstrap 4.3.1 libraries.

```
<link href="/style/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

P.S. Original code from w3schools contains bootstrap 3.4.0 libraries. If I use them everything works fine except one thing. I have gridview on my project. It has two columns and their headers titles are center aligned. If I use bootstrap 3.4.0 libraries, titles are left aligned and I can not change them. Actually, I did not look this problem deeply. I have focused on the problem with bootstrap 4.3.1 libraries.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**2.** I need to increase the width of modal windows. I tried some codes but it supports max. 500px. I couldn't find 500px entry in .css file. Which entry do I need to change or add?

Comment: This really isn't a C# or ASP.NET question. That's all handled by `css` and `Bootstrap`. You'll have better luck getting an answer if you remove the C# tag and add tags for css and Bootstrap

Comment: Hello @Flydog57, I edited the tags. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared `class="modal-title"` in header title.

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h1 class="modal-title">Test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @sebu, thank you for your answer. I added your recommendation, but nothing changed.

Comment: @echelon would you please update you question with full modal code and which bootstrap library you have used.

Comment: Hi @sebu, thank you for your time. I updated my question and added more details.

Comment: Hi @sebu, I used an example that creates modal with bootstrap 4 and problem is solved. Thank you again.